# MongoDB update from array value

Tags: mongodb

data.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aab67d9a0f7ef2e24860d09"),
"Name" : "Raj",
"status" : "pass",
"marks" : [ 
    {
        "M" : 95,
        "E" : 75,
        "H" : 60.0,
        "s" : "p"
    }, 
    {
        "M" : 56,
        "E" : 45,
        "H" : 60.0,
        "s" : "p"
    }
]
```

}

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aab689ea0f7ef2e24860d0b"),
"Name" : "Amit",
"status" : "Fail",
"marks" : [ 
    {
        "M" : 95,
        "E" : 75,
        "H" : 55,
        "s" : "p"
    }, 
    {
        "M" : 56,
        "E" : 30,
        "H" : 95,
        "s" : "f"
    }
]
```

}

This is my collection structure in mongoDb

I want to update the "status" field with value of 2nd object of "marks.s" 
I have tried

```
db.getCollection('test').updateMany(
  { $set : {"status" : "marks.1.s" } }
```

)

Error

```
Error:
```

TypeError: can't convert undefined to object :
DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:594:16
@(shell):1:1

Comment: You cant  pass value of an existing field as a variable in an `update` operation for now.

Comment: @Amit you have to use loop

Comment: @RahulRaj It is possible to update

Comment: @Krishna 
`Aggregation` is not an update operation

Comment: The problem to solve is update status field.

Answer (score 0):

This will update your whole collection getting the value of s from 2nd position and setting in status field of the document.

```
db.test.aggregate([   
{ "$addFields": { "status": {$arrayElemAt:[ "$marks.s",1]} }} ,
{ "$out": "test" }
]);
```

Comment: Doing an aggregation wont update your actual collection!

Comment: @RahulRaj give it a shot with the test data and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Alright, so you are indirectly updating the collection within an aggregation using an output operator. Good trick!

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
db.test.find().snapshot().forEach(function (item) 
       {db.test.update({_id: item._id},{$set: {status: item.marks[1].s}})});
```

iterate over the whole collection and for each item replace the status value with its marks value.